# How to Consume PHP rest service from asp.net application

Tags: php, jquery, asp.net, web-services

Some of our co-partner develop a web service in php  and give their web service consume address like this "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8081/ExposeWebservices/getLinkByLinkId.php" . Now it's our duty to consume those service in asp.net application. To consume their service by Jquery ajax i have tried a lot but i have no luck to achieve that. I have tried this way :

Here is my jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btnSearch').click(function () {

            var _linkId = $('#txtlinkId').val();
            if (_linkId === '') {
                alert('please input link id ');
                return;
            }

            // Here LDMAObject is javascript object
            var ldma = new LDMAObject(0, _linkId, 'getLinkByLinkId');

            var myCallback = function (data) {
                alert('callback'+data);
            };


            $.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                type: "GET",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                async: false,
                url: "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XX:8081/ExposeWebservices/getLinkByLinkId.php",
                data: { value: ldma.toJsonString() },
                dataType: "jsonp",
                jsonp: 'callback',
                jsonpCallback: myCallback,
                success: function (result) { alert('success' +result); },
                error: function (url,status,item) { alert('url='+url+'status='+status+'item='+item); }
            });



        });

    });
```

Here is my LDMAObject.js file code :

```
function generateUUID() {
var d = new Date().getTime();
var uuid = 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
    var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
    d = Math.floor(d / 16);
    return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x7 | 0x8)).toString(16);
});
return uuid;
};

function getFormattedDateTime() {
var zero = '0';
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate() < 10 ? zero + d.getDate() : d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1 < 10 ? zero + d.getMonth() : d.getMonth(); //Months are    zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
var curr_hour = d.getHours() < 10 ? zero + d.getHours() : d.getHours();
var curr_minute = d.getMinutes() < 10 ? zero + d.getMinutes() : d.getMinutes(); 
var curr_second = d.getSeconds() < 10 ? zero + d.getSeconds() : d.getSeconds();
var curr_milisecond = d.getMilliseconds() < 10 ? zero + d.getMilliseconds() : d.getMilliseconds();
return curr_year + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_date + " " + curr_hour + ":" + curr_minute + ":" + curr_second;
}


/* OOP  LDMAObject*/

function LDMAObject(flag,linkId,requestFuncName) { 


// Object private properties
   this.requestHeader = {
   requestID: generateUUID(),
   requestTime:  getFormattedDateTime(),
   requestLoginID: '', /* Id and password not given for security reason */
   requestPassword: '',
   requestFunction: requestFuncName
};
  this.requestParam = {
   flag: flag,
   linkId: linkId
  };

 this.toJsonString = function () { return JSON.stringify(this); };

  }
```

Here is my HTML :

```
<div class="myContentDiv">
    <div id="form">
        <h1>
            Search With LinkId :
        </h1>
        <label>
            LinkId :
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="txtlinkId" id="txtlinkId" />
        <input id="btnSearch" type="button" value="Search" />
        <div class="spacer">
        </div>
        <div id="lbl">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Some one Please Help me. I'm in hangout mode. Your help will be accepted from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: Have you used Fiddler2 (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to check the traffic of the requests and responses?

Comment: How are you authenticating? The WebService is asking for a username/password, but those are not send in your AJAX request.

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie I have used firefox addon restclient. the data i am passing through data property of jquery was working in restclient.But i have to say the method here we use in rest client is post but jsonp only accept get then how can i consume cross domain service ? please help .

Comment: Ignoring the possibility it is is a cross domain issue (and not just the credentials mentioned by magnetronnie), then you can secure the whole system by consuming the service *from your server only* and expose a new service of your own for client-side access. Otherwise you will be placing the credentials in readable client code!

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie please give me some example code

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie we use c#

Comment: As the service is secured by credentials and has no WSDL or other public documentation, you will need to figure that out from the docs they presumably provided to you. Then start Googling *"consuming JSON service from C#"* etc.